# Calculos em SQL

Tags: php, sql

Bom dia a todos,

Tenho uma duvida, tenho o seguinte Select SQL em que mostra o total da quantidade do produto, o sql esta a funcionar, porem mostra me os lotes repetidos.

```
SELECT stock.lote, stock.descricao,
CASE WHEN stock.tipo = 'XXXX' or stock.tipo = 'YYYY' or stock.tipo = 'ZZZZ'
     THEN +quantidade
     ELSE -quantidade
     END as quant FROM stock
     INNER JOIN lotes
        ON lotes.descricao = stock.lote AND lotes.active=1
     WHERE stock.descricao = 'NORMAL' AND stock.lote!=''
```

Resultado do select:

| lote | descrição | quant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lote1 | prod1 | 5 |
| lote2 | prod1 | 5 |
| lote2 | prod1 | -11 |

Resultado do select que eu pretendo: (ja tentei usar o GROUP BY e nao funcionou.)

| lote | descrição | quant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lote1 | prod1 | 5 |
| lote2 | prod1 | -6 |

alguem pode ajudar? obrigado

Comment: Tentou com left join no lugar do Inner Join? Ou a função SUM()?

Comment: O left join não altera nada, como uso o sum neste select?

Comment: tenta usar `+SUM(quantidade)` ou `-SUM(quantidade)` e dá um group by pela `stock.lote`

Comment: @WallaceMagalhães acho que não vai funcionar, aplicando dessa forma retornaria ou o valor positivo ou o valor negativo e não a diferença entre eles. Talvez seja caso de usar uma temporária.

Comment: Perfeito, era mesmo isso que precisava, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você precisa é fazer a soma dos valores retornados no seu `CASE`, usando apenas o `group by` seria mostrado apenas um dos valores, possivelmente o último, então acredito que se você usar o `SUM()` como abaixo vá funcionar. Caso não dê me fale que edito a resposta com uma nova sugestão.

```
SELECT stock.lote,
       stock.descricao,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN stock.tipo = 'XXXX'
                   OR stock.tipo = 'YYYY'
                   OR stock.tipo = 'ZZZZ' THEN +quantidade
             ELSE -quantidade
           END) AS quant
FROM   stock
       INNER JOIN lotes
               ON lotes.descricao = stock.lote
                  AND lotes.active = 1
WHERE  stock.descricao = 'NORMAL'
       AND stock.lote != ''
GROUP  BY stock.lote
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve utilizar o GROUP BY com a cláusula SUM.  O GROUP BY é utilizado para agrupar os campos.

No seu caso todos os ***"lotes e descrição"*** que sejam iguais serão agrupados e seus valores somados.

```
SELECT  stock.lote, stock.descricao, sum(stock.tipo) as stock.tipo 
  from  stock 
        INNER JOIN lotes ON  lotes.descricao = stock.lote 
                         AND lotes.active=1
  WHERE stock.descricao = 'NORMAL'
    AND stock.lote!='' 
  group by stock.lote, stock.descricao
```